# Limit number of times a Class can be instantiated

Tags: javascript, class, instance

The following question was asked in a JavaScript interview.

> After creating 3 instances of a class, how to prevent further instance creation?

What is the answer for this?

Comment: You could throw an error in the constructor

Comment: This is the type of problem that the factory pattern solves, as touched on below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming the question requires that you get "clever" and not use any globals nor other classes.

You can use a [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) method to keep track of created instances. From then on you can throw errors in the `constructor` to prevent instantiation.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name) {
    if (Foo.maxInstancesReached())
      throw 'Max instances reached'

    this.name = name
  }

  static maxInstancesReached() {
    if (!this.numOfCreatedInstances)
      this.numOfCreatedInstances = 0

    return ++this.numOfCreatedInstances > 3
  }
}

const foo1 = new Foo('Jack')
const foo2 = new Foo('John')
const foo3 = new Foo('Mary')
const foo4 = new Foo('Rebecca')
```

Comment: @RobG Don't edit valid code style in my code. I'm omitting semicolons in JS **on purpose**. Also your "logging" only adds extra noise.

Comment: Fine, but all your code *appears* to do is throw an error. Answers should be good answers, they aren't supposed to necessarily be what you'd do in production code. Omitting semicolons is not considered a good idea, but that's your choice I guess.

Comment: It is a good answer by nature that it answers the OP's directly. The edit was unnecessary. Omitting semicolons is in-fact a very good idea, since JS automatically inserts them for you - I suggest you adopt the practise. Let's move on.

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved through the use of a factory function:

```js
class Special {
}

let specialObjectCounter = 0;
function createSpecial() {
  // factory function
  if (specialObjectCounter === 3) return;
  specialObjectCounter++;
  return new Special();
}

const a = createSpecial();
const b = createSpecial();
const c = createSpecial();
const d = createSpecial();
const e = createSpecial();

console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
```

A more generic version would look like this:

```js
function instanceLimiter(proto, count, action=()=>undefined) {
  let counter = 0;
  return function(...args) {
    if (counter >= count) return action();
    counter++;
    return new proto(...args);
  }
}


// Demo
class Special {
}

const createSpecial = instanceLimiter(Special, 3);

const res = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(createSpecial);

console.log(...res);
```

If you prefer throwing instead of returning `undefined` you can just pass a different `action` to `instanceLimiter`:

```
instanceLimiter(Special, 3, () => {throw 'Maximum instance count reached'});
```

Comment: I prefer this approach to throwing errors, though it would be nice to keep the counter private. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Created a static variable and increment the count each time a new instance is created. If the `count` reaches the threshold, throw an error.

```js
var Foo = function() {
  if (Foo.instances >= 3) {
    throw new Error("Max number of instances reached");
  }

  Foo.instances++;
};

Foo.instances = 0;

var a = new Foo();
console.log(a);

var b = new Foo();
console.log(b);

var c = new Foo();
console.log(c);

console.log(Foo.instances);

var d = new Foo();
console.log(d);
```